# Provide link to lightbox image

Tags: php, jquery

I'm using a light box(jquery.lightbox-0.5.js) for my gallery page. And my code for display the image is

```
<ul>
  <div class="gallery" id="gallery1">
    <li> <a style="display: inline;" href="sample.jpg" target="_blank"> <img src="sample_thumb.jpg" alt=""  /> </a> </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

It's working fine.

But now i want to provide the link to the Lightbox image. i.e., On clicking the Image within the Lightbox, i want to redirect the user to some other page.

But i dont know how to achieve this? Does anyone have any idea about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set title of the "a" tag in your html and set it to the link you want. when image is clicked, on the enlarged image's bottom you will see a link where you can click and navigate.

```
<ul>
  <div class="gallery" id="gallery1">
    <li> <a style="display: inline;" href="sample.jpg" target="_blank" title="&lt;a href='http://google.com'&gt;My Link. Click Me&lt;/a&gt;"> <img src="sample_thumb.jpg" alt=""  /> </a> </li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's working. Is it possible to having the link on the image?

Comment: On which, when it is enlarged OR on the thumb. the problem is , the "A" tag is already used by plugin

Comment: Link on the enlarged one. is it possible?

Comment: so don't you need next and previous functionality?

Comment: Need both. On the Next and Previous icon, i want the "Next" and "Previous" functionality. But on the Image, i need to put the link.

Comment: Not possible, will have to change the plugin code. which is not convenient. sorry. thats the limit of the plugin then.